# remove all duplicate and orginal elements from array if duplicate is present in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var techologylist=[1,2,2,3,4,4,5]
var newtechologylist=[];
$.each(techologylist, function (i, el) {
   if ($.inArray(el, newtechologylist) === -1) newtechologylist.push(el);
});
console.log(newtechologylist)
```

I want to remove values from techologylist ,if same 2 value comes .In my example 2 and 4 comes twice ,therefore i want to remove both 2 and 4 from array
Am expecting result as `[1,3,5]`

But result for my code of course give result as `[1,2,3,4,5]`

How to change my script to remove both values if duplicate occurs

Comment: I believe I just removed a duplicate from the `questions` array...

Comment: I think it is not duplicate.Both cases are different

Comment: And to attempt to answer the question, I'd have two Objects, one of which keeps track of all values seen, and the other which will contain the output. Loop through the input, if the current value is in the first Object already, delete it from the output Object. If it's not in the first Object, add it to both.

Comment: Right, misleading title much... Reopened.

Comment: var techologylist=[1,2,2,3,4,4,5];
var newtechologylist=[];
$.each(techologylist, function (i, el) {
  if ($.inArray(el, newtechologylist) === -1) {
    newtechologylist.push(el);
  } else {
    var index = newtechologylist.indexOf(el);
    if (index > -1) {
      newtechologylist.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});
console.log(newtechologylist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var techologylist = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
var newtechologylist = [];

$.each(techologylist , function (i, el) {
    
    if ($.inArray(el, newtechologylist ) === -1) {
        newtechologylist.push(el);
    } 
    
    else {
        var index = newtechologylist.indexOf(el);
        if(index > -1){
           newtechologylist.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});

document.write(newtechologylist);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks ozil ,exactly what i want